# How to limit to maximum count of rows in single table in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table, with the following columns:

- Id           BigInt
- CustomerId   BigInt
- Order        varchar(50)
- DateOfOrder  date

What I try to achieve is the following:
Getting all CustomerId, which have a specific string for the column order and the DateOfOrder is since 2018 and from this only the last two orders.

I started with the following SQL-Statement

```
Select o.CustomerId as CustomerId, o.Id as Id 
  from order o 
 where o.Order="Merchandise" 
   and year(o.DateOfOrder)>= 2018 
 order by o.DateOfOrder desc;
```

But how do I get only the 2 top orders of each CustomerId?

THX a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking for is called `row_number` and you should use it with `Subquery` in order to get 2 top orders of each `CustomerId` based on `DateOfOrder`

```
 SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      o.customerid AS customerid, 
      o.id AS id,
       row_number() over (
        partition by o.customerid 
        ORDER BY  o.DateOfOrder  DESC
      --ORDER BY  o.Order   DESC
      ) rn 
    FROM 
      ORDER o 
    WHERE 
      o.ORDER = "Merchandise" 
      AND year(o.dateoforder)>= 2018
  ) 
WHERE 
  rn <= 2
```

for lower versions of Mysql that does not support `row_number` use `correlated-subquery`

```
 SELECT o1.id ,
       o1.customerid ,
       o1.order ,
       o1.dateoforder
FROM   order O1
WHERE  2 >
       (
              SELECT Count(*)
              FROM   order O2
              WHERE  o1.customerid = o2.customerid
              AND    o1.order > o2.order )
AND
o1.ORDER="Merchandise"
AND    year(o1.dateoforder)>= 2018
```

Comment: Hey @RF191
THX for your sample. But wouldn't this only get all the customers, which have maximum 2 orders within this time?
This isn't what I try to achieve. Because it could be, that the customer has more than 2 orders within this time. So it must be the TOP 2 orders.
THX

Comment: does commented expression solve your issue.

Comment: @RF191 I get an error at "row_number" The error says: " row_number is not valid at this position, expecting For, Lock, ..."

Comment: row_number is mySQL8 only. You cannot use it with mySQL5.7

Comment: I have changed my answer, that does fit to your problem.

Comment: Hey
No, sorry... - Still the same problem. Once again, I try to explain in a differnent way:
It could be, that one customer has 10 orders, since 2018. All matching the Order "Merchandise". But I only want the last two orders.
With your query, I get all customers, which have 2 orders at all.
THX

Answer (score 0):

I think, I solved my problem.
Not beatuiful, but working.
If someone is interested in the solution:
First I get all oldest Orders into a Temporary Table.
Then I get second oldest orders, by using the id of the oldest orders, which are not allowed to be in the query The result is also stored in a temporary table..
And then, I union the results of the temporary tables to get my data, which I wanted to have.

```
Create Temporary Table Top_Orders 
    Select o.Id Id, o.CustomerId CustomerId, Max(o.DateOfOrder) OrderDate from order o where o.Order = "Merchandise" and year(o.DateOfOrder) >= 2018 group by CustomerId;
    
Create Temporary Table Top_Orders2
    Select o.Id Id, o.CustomerId CustomerId, Max(o.DateOfOrder) OrderDate from order o where o.Order = "Merchandise" and year(o.DateOfOrder) >= 2018 and o.Id not in (Select Id from Top_Orders) group by CustomerId;
    
Select o1.CustomerID, o1.Id from order o1 where o1.Id in (Select t1.Id from Top_Orders t1) union Select o2.CustomerId, o2.Id from order o2 where o2.Id in (Select t2.Id from Top_Orders2 t2);
    
Drop Temporary Table Top_Orders;
Drop Temporary Table Top_Orders2;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).